# How to check that user is SharePoint administrator in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

How to check (on C#) that user which entered my SharePoint app **(provider-hosted app)** is **SharePoint administrator** and not just **SiteCollection administrator** but **tenant administrator** also.

Comment: Did you find away to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.CurrentUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine("Is Site Admin: " + clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin);
```